# connection between c++ and cplex

Tags: visual-c++

I am more or less beginner in programming. I need to make a connection between c++ and CPLEX. I don't know how I have to do. I am very grateful if everyone would help me or introduce some links.

Answer (score 1):

Concert is a set of C++, Java and .NET libraries that lets you interface smoothly to the cplex. Not too sure about the C++ API but I have worked extensively with the Java API and it is quite straight forward.

Take a look at the API and this [tutorial](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX86.html). Let us know if you have any specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two alternatives:

**1) Use Concert Technology**

Concert Technology is a complex set of classes, which enables you to write models in an oo-way. It works with C++ and is quite convenient. Though with Java or C# it's maybe a little easier to handle.

[Concert Technology tutorial by IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX86.html)

**2) Use the Callable Library**

The callable library is not object oriented, but you can do anything with it. Its a huge set of functions to build, modify and solve models. All you need is the cplex.dll and some headers for type and function declarations. It is not as convenient as Concert and you have to do more things "manually", but you have full control over what you are doing. The Callable Library works with C as well.

[Callable Library tutorial by IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX86.html)